# How to change the speed of an NPC?

Tags: ai, unreal-4, blueprints

I created a blueprint. I added several components to the blueprint. I made it follow a target point and it does it correctly. I'd like to make the NPC make this way to the target point faster, but I do not know how to set the speed.

**How I Created:**

[image]

**Components of the NPC:**

[image]

I've clicked on all components looking for a way to set their speed. I also clicked **Class Settings** and **Class Defaults**, but nothing resulted.

**Then I tried to find some function or command related to the speed, taking a reference from the NPC itself:**

[image]

**I added values ​​to tranform, but did not change the result in the game at all:**

[image]

**Links that I clicked at the time I typed the title of the question:**

[How do I change the speed of an object without changing path travelled?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7939/how-do-i-change-the-speed-of-an-object-without-changing-path-travelled)

[Changing speed of an object](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/122403/changing-speed-of-an-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you consider setting `maxwalkspeed` and `maxrunspeed` ? Go to `CharacterMovementComponent` [API docs page](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/UCharacterMovementComponent/index.html), and check-out the list. You will find a lot of configurable movement modes and if you are unsatisfied, you can make your own.

The functions are blueprint callable for a blueprint class deriving from character/pawn. For using in C++ class, include `UCharacterMovementComponent.h` .

**In NPC Blueprint, on the Components tab, click in CharacterMovement:**

[image]

**Look for the "Character Movement Walking":**

[image]

Modify the option that is circled (default value was 600).